# Xamarin Binding Libriary 'Overlay': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, dll, binding

I'm need rename field "Overlay", but not remove.
I'm try make link native jar lib to xamarin dll. 
I`m create new Binding Libriary project and include jar file inside.
But when i'm try build solution, system output window get error

> 'Overlay': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type.

I'm try configurate MetaData file in the following way.

```
<metadata>
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='Com.Cdcom.Naviapps.Progorod']/class[@name='Overlay']/method[@name='Overlay']" />
</metadata>
```

or

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='Com.Cdcom.Naviapps.Progorod']/class[@name='Overlay']" />
```

or i'm try change EnumMethods

```
<enum-method-mappings>
  <mapping jni-class="/api/package[@name='com.cdcom.naviapps.progorod']/class[@name='Overlay']">
<method jni-name="Overlay" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Android.OS.Overlay" />
  </mapping>
</enum-method-mappings>
```

but i'm get other error

> "generator.exe" exited with code -532462766.

You can see the class from first error below

```
// Metadata.xml XPath class reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.cdcom.naviapps.progorod']/class[@name='Overlay']"
    [global::Android.Runtime.Register ("com/cdcom/naviapps/progorod/Overlay", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
    public partial class Overlay : global::Java.Lang.Object {
        //region "Event implementation for Com.Cdcom.Naviapps.Progorod.Overlay.IOnOverlayListener"
        public event EventHandler<global::Com.Cdcom.Naviapps.Progorod.Overlay.OverlayEventArgs> Overlay {
            add {
                global::Java.Interop.EventHelper.AddEventHandler<global::Com.Cdcom.Naviapps.Progorod.Overlay.IOnOverlayListener, global::Com.Cdcom.Naviapps.Progorod.Overlay.IOnOverlayListenerImplementor>(
                        ref weak_implementor___SetOnOverlayListener,
                        __CreateIOnOverlayListenerImplementor,
                        __v => OnOverlayListener = __v,
                        __h => __h.Handler += value);
            }
            remove {
                global::Java.Interop.EventHelper.RemoveEventHandler<global::Com.Cdcom.Naviapps.Progorod.Overlay.IOnOverlayListener, global::Com.Cdcom.Naviapps.Progorod.Overlay.IOnOverlayListenerImplementor>(
                        ref weak_implementor___SetOnOverlayListener,
                        global::Com.Cdcom.Naviapps.Progorod.Overlay.IOnOverlayListenerImplementor.__IsEmpty,
                        __v => OnOverlayListener = null,
                        __h => __h.Handler -= value);
            }
        }
        //endregion
    }
```

Original java code

```
public class Overlay
{
  public List<OverlayItem> getItems()
  {
    return this.mOverlayItems;
  }
    public OnOverlayListener getOnOverlayListener()
  {
    return this.mOverlayListener;
  }

  public void populate()
  {
    double[] latlon = new double[this.mOverlayItems.size() * 2];
    int d = 0;
    for (OverlayItem oi : this.mOverlayItems)
    {
      latlon[(d++)] = oi.getGeoPoint().getLatitude();
      latlon[(d++)] = oi.getGeoPoint().getLongitude();
    }
    Native.populateOverlay(this.mId, latlon);
  }
  public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float xOffset, float yOffset, boolean isPlain, int sizeInMeters)
  {
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int[] pixels = null;
    if (bitmap != null)
    {
      width = bitmap.getWidth();
      height = bitmap.getHeight();
      pixels = new int[width * height];
      bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    }
    Native.setOverlayBitmap(this.mId, width, height, pixels, xOffset, yOffset, isPlain, sizeInMeters);
  }
  public void setOnOverlayListener(OnOverlayListener listener)
  {
    this.mOverlayListener = listener;
  }

  public static int SPECIAL_OVERLAY_START_ROUTE = -1;
  public static int SPECIAL_OVERLAY_FINISH_ROUTE = -2;
  public static int SPECIAL_OVERLAY_ROUTE_SPRITE = -3;
  public static int SPECIAL_OVERLAY_GEOBLOG_SPRITE = -4;
  private static int SPECIAL_OVERLAYS_COUNT = 4;

  public static Overlay specialOverlay(int id)
  {
    if (mSpecialOverlays[(id + SPECIAL_OVERLAYS_COUNT)] == null)
    {
      mSpecialOverlays[(id + SPECIAL_OVERLAYS_COUNT)] = new Overlay();
      mSpecialOverlays[(id + SPECIAL_OVERLAYS_COUNT)].mId = id;
    }
    return mSpecialOverlays[(id + SPECIAL_OVERLAYS_COUNT)];
  }

  protected int getId()
  {
    return this.mId;
  }

  protected int mId = mNextId++;
  private static int mNextId = 1;
  private List<OverlayItem> mOverlayItems = new ArrayList();
  private OnOverlayListener mOverlayListener;
  private static Overlay[] mSpecialOverlays = new Overlay[SPECIAL_OVERLAYS_COUNT];

  public static abstract interface OnOverlayListener
  {
    public abstract void onOverlayEvent(Overlay paramOverlay, OverlayItem paramOverlayItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the original Java codes in `com.cdcom.naviapps.progorod.Overlay`?

Comment: Thanks, i'm added java source.